# Entity Framework database first adding new table to exist .edmx

Tags: entity-framework, ef-database-first

I added a new table to the database. In the `.edmx` (where database diagram is at), I right-clicked and chose 'Update Model from Database...'. I can see the new table's diagram has been generated, but how do I add model to EXISTING `.tt`? I know I could do it manually, but I would like to know how to generate it automatically. Thanks.

EDIT: I got the model class by clicking around. I think it was right clicking on `.tt` then 'Debug T4 template' which generated it. But can anybody explain what did this Debug T4 template debug?